# How to fill values between to dates rows using pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have a dataset with with an id column, an event date column and in_event boolean. 
The event date might have a date value in it.

```
[[1,None],[2,'01-01-2018'],[3,None],[4,'01-02-2018']]
```

I need to fill the in_event column for all the rows between each event dates.

result would be:

```
1, None,        False
2, 01-01-2018,  True
3, None,        True
4, 01-02-2018,  True
```

Any idea how to do that using pyspark?

Comment: I don't think your data provides enough information to do this. It's possible to find previous values and make decision based on that, but if you had more than one event in the table, e.g. 
```
[[1,None],[2,'01-01-2018'],[3,None],[4,'01-02-2018'], [5, None], [6,'01-04-2018']]
```
how can you tell which two dates correspond to which event and how many events were there at all? 1, 2, 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import rand, randn, udf, abs, signum
from pyspark.sql.types import (IntegerType, StructType, StructField, StringType, BooleanType)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()

column_schema = StructType([StructField("id", IntegerType()), StructField("event_date", StringType())])
data = [[1, None], [2, '01-01-2018'], [3, None], [4, '01-02-2018']]

data_frame = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=column_schema)
data_frame = data_frame.withColumn("in_event", (signum(rand()-.2)+1).cast(BooleanType()))
data_frame.show()
```

> output

```
| id|event_date|in_event|
+---+----------+--------+
|  1|      null|    true|
|  2|01-01-2018|    true|
|  3|      null|    true|
|  4|01-02-2018|   false|
+---+----------+--------+
```

Comment: Not sure if this is real or am I missing something but would be nice to know why signum of random number will do anything here?

Comment: since original data wasnt provided for boolean attribute. signum and random helps you to generate boolean values from gaussian distribution